# Trying to understand legacy PCL file

Tags: printing

I have a client who is migrating from Samsung printer to Sharp. One "critical" print job they need to do involves printing barcodes on sticky labels for shipping. The print job is being generated by a piece of VERY old software whose origin is in the pre-Smartphone era (and probably no source code).

The barcode font is in a recognizable PCL file and can be uploaded to the Sharp. The actual print job, on the other hand, I sort of see pieces of PCL escape sequences but not in any form the Sharp (or even a HP) could do anything useful with.

For example, I see the sequence "&l1O" (hex 26 6c 31 4f) which, if it were preceded by an ESC, would select landscape mode. What I see instead is (in hex) 1b 15 36 before the "&l1O". In other places, wherever I expect a PCL escape sequence I am seeing similar 3-octet groupings: 1b 15 37, 1b 14 21, etc. instead of a single 1b preceding the PCL command.

So my question: Can anybody please point me to documentation or site that would help me interpret these sequences. I am thinking if I know what the original file is doing I can write a filter to run the file through to produce something useful.

BTW, I have gone through the PCL5 Technical Ref manual and these are not mentioned anywhere in it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These commands are documented under "Primary and Secondary Fonts" in the HP PCL5 Technical Reference:

> The printer maintains two independent font select tables for use in
>   selecting a primary font and a secondary font. All of the
>   characteristics previously described apply to both tables. This
>   provides access to two distinct fonts, only one of which is selected
>   at a given time. To alternate between the primary and the secondary
>   font, the control codes ‘‘SI’’ (Shift In; ASCII 15) is used to
>   designate primary and ‘‘SO’’ (Shift Out; ASCII 14) is used to
>   designate secondary.